# Give focus to an control when the App starts in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have multiple TextFiled controls, and can I put a focus on a specific TextField when the App starts?

### EDIT

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
...
    [commandInput becomeFirstResponder];
...
}
```

works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, use 
[textfield1 becomeFirstResponder]